# AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.1 error for new project in android studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I am trying to build a blank pro[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfkkb.png)enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0bSG.png)q.png)

`Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform appcompat-1.6.1.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\ibl149561.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a8030d394e32267064d54a03a1ed067f\transformed\appcompat-1.6.1.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.1-7984345-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWcUc.png)

Comment: try to increment Android Gradle Plugin Version from '7.4' to '7.4.2'

& 

Increment Gradle Version '7.4' to '7.5'. Then Rebuild ur project.

Comment: tried with agp version 7.2.2 and gradle version 7.5 getting same error
AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.2-7984345-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime